# How to calculate expected return, row by row in matrix?

Tags: functions, matrix

Please help me, I'm writing my project and dont know how to solve this big matrix:

[image]

I have to compute return row by row: 1st row: (18.32-17.14)/17.14 ;  (19.17-18.32)/18.32  ....
                                     2nd row:(11.79-13.86)/13.86 ;  (11.37-11.79)/11.79  ....

Comment: Look up `Differences` and `Most` in the help. Also, `Listable` functions.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's really a great help to me.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized and probably not useful for future visitors.

Comment: I didn't know `Differences` so I found it a useful question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
m = {{17.14, 18.32, 19.17, 20.63},
     {13.86, 11.79, 11.37, 13.45},
     {49.9, 48.77, 52.3, 56.87}};

compute = Partition[#, 2, 1] /. {a_, b_} :> b/a - 1 &;

compute /@ m
```

> {{0.0688448, 0.0463974, 0.0761607}, {-0.149351, -0.0356234, 
>     0.182938}, {-0.0226453, 0.0723806, 0.0873805}}

Alternatively:

```
m = {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}};

compute = (Ratios@#) - 1 &;

compute /@ m
```

> {{-1 + b/a, -1 + c/b}, {-1 + e/d, -1 + f/e}}

**Edit**

Some timings :-

```
Clear[o, p, q, r]
Subsets[{o, p, q, r}, {2}]
m = RandomReal[20, {3000, 3000}];

f1 = (Differences@#/Most@#) &;
f2 = Partition[#, 2, 1] /. {a_, b_} :> b/a - 1 &;
f3 = (Ratios@#) - 1 &;
f4 = (Rest@#/Most@#) - 1 &;

o = f1 /@ m;
p = f2 /@ m;
q = f3 /@ m;
r = f4 /@ m;
Equal @@@ Subsets[{o, p, q, r}, {2}]
Flatten[Chop[#1 - #2] & @@@ Subsets[{o, p, q, r}, {2}]] // Union
```

> {{o, p}, {o, q}, {o, r}, {p, q}, {p, r}, {q, r}}
>
> {False, False, False, False, True, False}
>
> {-1.16415*10^-10, 0, 1.16415*10^-10}

Only `f2` and `f4` produce exactly the same results, but the differences are all minute.

```
t = First@Timing[# /@ m] &;
t /@ {f1, f2, f3, f4}
```

> {0.216709, 14.198865, 0.179863, 0.145772}

The `Partition` method, (`f2`), is by far the slowest!

Answer (score 1):

```
m = {{a, b, d}, {d, e, f}}
Differences /@ m /Most /@ m
(*
{{(-a + b)/a, (-b + d)/b}, {(-d + e)/d, (-e + f)/e}}
*)
```